# Are all the Lie bialgebra structure on $sl_n$ coboundary?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-groups, integrable-systems

In the case of $sl_2$, there are three Lie bialgebra structures. We have three cobrackets $\delta: sl_2 \to \Lambda^2 sl_2$. Each $\delta$ can be written as $\delta=d r$ for some matrix $r$. Therefore all the Lie bialgebra structure on $sl_2$ are coboundary. Are all the Lie bialgebra structure on $sl_n$ coboundary for each $n$?

Comment: As Makoto Yamashita writes it is because H^2(semisimpleLieAlg) = 0 - "Whitehead's lemma" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead%27s_lemma_(Lie_algebras)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compatibility between bracket and cobracket $\delta$ can be interpreted as $\delta$ being a $1$-cocycle. Then Whitehead's lemma implies the existence of such $r$.